# is switch case without break a bad practice?

Tags: c, switch-statement

I have a switch in which I check a property of some sort and if the check yields a specific value, I want to check another value, so I did something like this:

```
switch(property_A)
{
case NA:
    if(value_0 == property_B)
        property_A = value_a;
    else if(value_1 == property_B)
        property_A = value_b;
case value_0:
...
break;
case value_1:
...
break;
}
```

So, I know this solves my problem, but I don't know if this is a good idea or maybe should I go about this another way

# the NA case is something like a default case but not exactly, because it does tell me something, but not enough

Comment: If you are trying to jump to the correct case after preforming what's in `NA`, it won't work.

Comment: It's common to allow a case to "fall through" to the next case. However, what you're doing does not "check another value". If you modify the value being switched on and want to run the `switch` from the start you need a loop.

Comment: Do you want the code in `case value_o` to execute if you hit the `case NA` ?

Comment: wihtout break I just go to the next case, no matter what my property_A value is?

Comment: Yes. That's what "fall through" means, the code will just continue. It "falls through" the bottom of the current `case` and continues with the next one below it.

Comment: can I make the code go back to the switch and pick the new case WO a loop or a second switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. If you get to the case `NA`, without the `break` keyword, the `value_0` case will be executed after one of the two `if` branches is finished. So if that's the behaviour you want, it's OK not to use `break`, but I don't think that's what you wanted to do.

I suggest you simply move the `if - else` statement above the `switch` and remove the `NA` case. This way, you will first assign the correct data to `property_A` and then you can do whatever you want with it in the `switch`.

EDIT: As [Jack Deeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2449857/jack-deeth) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40913224/15168), if you omitted the `break` statement on purpose, it's a good idea to add a comment that you did so.

Answer (score 4):

Convention is to add a comment explicitly telling future-you and any other maintainers you intended the fallthough and you haven't accidentally omitted the `break;`.

```
switch(foo) {
case 1:
  bar();
  // fallthrough
case 2:
  baz();
  break;
case 3:
  fizzbuzz();
}
```

If you're using C++17 or later you can use the `[[fallthrough]]` attribute to avoid a compiler warning:

```
switch(foo) {
case 1:
  bar();
  [[fallthrough]]
case 2:
  baz();
  break;
case 3:
  fizzbuzz();
}
```

Comment: I indeed added a comment, but wanted to know if it is a bad practice even with a comment

Answer (score 2):

The additional information provided in the comments to the question indicate that what's wanted is not what's written in the question:

```
switch(property_A)
{
  case NA:
    if(value_0 == property_B)
        property_A = value_a;
    else if(value_1 == property_B)
        property_A = value_b;
    // here, we fallthrough into the code for value_0
    // but you want to switch on the new value instead
  case value_0:
    ...
    break;
}
```

What you say you actually want is to set `property_A` if it was initially `NA`, then jump to the correct label.  In that case, you'll need the assignment to be outside of the `switch` statement.  You could do this with a `goto` at the end of the `NA` case, but I recommend you just deal with the `NA` before the switch:

```
if (property_A==NA)
    property_A = (value_0 == property_B) ? value_a
               : (value_1 == property_B) ? value_b
               : NA;

switch (property_A) {
  case value_0:
    ...
    break;
  case NA:
    // we get here only if none of the replacement conditions
    // matched, outside the 'case'
}
```